# Python sockethandler logging not working for some modules

Tags: python, logging, config

I have an odd problem.  I am using logging.config to setup my logger to use the sockethandler.  Everything works fine except 2/10+ modules don't seem to be logging anything.  By fine, I mean I see output on my log server for everything except for the two.  It's so odd that it works for some but not others.  I'm initializing the logger for every module with the following lines:

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig(config.main_log_conf)
logger = logging.getLogger("CAKE")
```

I thought the problem was might've been conflicting logger names, thus the CAKE above, but that didn't work.

Below is the conf file I'm using.

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=socketHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
handlers=socketHandler
level=DEBUG

[handler_socketHandler]
class=handlers.SocketHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('localhost', handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Comment: In your comment, what do you mean by "processes (not subprocesses)"? subprocesses *are* processes, and any process started by a process is a subprocess.

Comment: Meant I am using Process from Multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `fileConfig()` from every module. There should generally be just one call to set up the logging configuration in a program (process), called from the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause. Also note that you should (in general) pass `disable_existing_loggers=False` to `fileConfig` - the default is `True` only for backward compatibility reasons. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig) for more information.

Comment: Do processes (not subprocesses) launched from the main process have to call fileconfig?

Comment: Setting disable_existing_loggers=False makes a lot of debug logging from python modules start printing...weird